# How to get ec2 instance state at CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I can see my instance with:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances --output text
RESERVATIONS    193693970645    r-06e25c9702ca1a586
INSTANCES       0       x86_64          False   True    xen     ami-00c03f7f7f2ec15c3   i-03006b8712ac593f9     t2.micro        mdaws   2019-10-11T12:08:56.000Z                    /dev/xvda       ebs     User initiated (2019-10-11 12:51:09 GMT)        hvm
CAPACITYRESERVATIONSPECIFICATION        open
CPUOPTIONS      1       1
HIBERNATIONOPTIONS      False
MONITORING      disabled
PLACEMENT       us-east-2c              default
STATE   48      terminated
STATEREASON     Client.UserInitiatedShutdown    Client.UserInitiatedShutdown: User initiated shutdown
```

but how can I pick out the termination code (48) or description (terminated) when I just want a few fields ?

I have tried a few things including:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId, ImageId, State]" --output text

'str' object has no attribute 'items'

$ aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId, ImageId, State[*]]" --output text
i-03006b8712ac593f9     ami-00c03f7f7f2ec15c3   None

$ aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId, ImageId, State[*].[Code]]" --output text
i-03006b8712ac593f9     ami-00c03f7f7f2ec15c3   None

$ aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId, ImageId, State[*].[Code[*]]]" --output text
i-03006b8712ac593f9     ami-00c03f7f7f2ec15c3   None
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format is `[InstanceId, ImageId, State.Code, State.Name]`, i.e.

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances \
--query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId, ImageId, State.code, State.Name]" --o text
```

Output in this example:

```
i-03006b8712ac593f9     ami-00c03f7f7f2ec15c3   48    terminated
```

Comment: I think it's not bad to accept your own answer so the community will not visit your question. answered but not accepted normally mean that question still looking for answer as I am here because of this.

Comment: Yes.  However I have to wait two days before being allowed to accept my own answer (SO limit).  Still waiting for that time period to elapse.