# Hello all could you please anyone helpus How to get the Instance state using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services

How to get the Instance state in AWS CLI.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get ec2 instance state at CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58356635/how-to-get-ec2-instance-state-at-cli)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `aws ec2 describe-instance-status` CLI call
https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instance-status.html

OR

use the `aws ec2 describe-instances` call and check the attribute `instance-state-name`

https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ec2 describe instance command like so:

1. To get the details about a particular instance

```
aws ec2 describe-instance-status --instance-id <instance-id>
```

2. To get details about all the instances for the account ([official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instance-status.html)):

```
aws ec2 describe-instances
```